# ¿Por qué no me inserta datos en MySQL desde PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo este código en la vista, creo que el problema son los checkbox, que lo uso como un `boolean`, y luego por eso no me arroja.

```
<form action="darAltaAlojamiento.php" method="post">
        <input name="localizacion" type="text"placeholder="localizacion" ></br></br>
        <input name="numeroHabitaciones" type="number"placeholder="numero de habitaciones"></br></br>
        <input name="incluidaMediaPension"type="checkbox">Incluir media pensión</br></br>
        <input name="fumador"type="checkbox">fumador</br></br>
        <input name="ninios"type="checkbox">niños</br></br>
        <input name="mascotas"type="checkbox">mascotas</br></br>
        <input name="fechaEntrada" type="date"> Fecha Entrada</br></br>
        <input name="fechaSalida" type="date"> Fecha Salida</br></br>

         <!-- Borrar los valores -->
  <label for="Borrar">¿Quieres resetear?</label>
  <input type="reset" value="Borrar">

  <!-- Recoger los datos -->
  <label for="Enviar">Enviar</label>
  <input type="submit" name="Enviar">
    </form>
```

Después de este código pasa a este otro código:

```
<?php
require('conexion.php');
if ( $_POST["localizacion"] != ""&& $_POST["numeroHabitaciones"] != ""&&  $_POST["incluidaMediaPension"] != ""&& 
  $_POST["fumador"] != ""&& $_POST["ninios"] != ""
  &&  $_POST["mascotas"] != ""&&  $_POST["fechaEntrada"] != ""
  &&  $_POST["fechaSalida"] != "") {

    //Contruir consulta y mirar si hay fila
    $localizacion= $_POST["localizacion"];

    $consulta = 'SELECT localizacion FROM alojamientos where localizacion = "'.$localizacion.'"';
    $results=$conn->query($consulta);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results)==0)
    {
    print("No Existen registros");
    $numeroHabitaciones=$_POST["numeroHabitaciones"];
    $incluidaMediaPension=$_POST["incluidaMediaPension"];
    $fumador=$_POST["fumador"];
    $ninios=$_POST["ninios"];
    $mascotas=$_POST["mascotas"];
    $fechaEntrada=$_POST["fechaEntrada"];
    $fechaSalida=$_POST["fechaSalida"];
    //Insertar datos
    $sql="INSERT INTO alojamientos (localizacion, numeroHabitaciones, incluidaMediaPension
    ,fumador,ninios,mascotas,fechaEntrada,fechaSalida)
    VALUES ('$localizacion',$numeroHabitaciones,$incluidaMediaPension,$fumador,$ninios,$mascotas,$fechaEntrada,$fechaSalida)";

    if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE){
        echo " inserted data";
    }else{
        echo "failed";
    }
```

He puesto un inserta literal, donde el true es `1` y false es `0` pero con `0` no me lo admite, y también las fechas que sale `0000`.

Comment: La raíz del problema viene por lo mal que estás formando el SQL. Deberías usar [consultas preparadas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) y no concatenación de cadenas. Por otro lado debes comprender que los `type="checkbox"` mandan o no un valor por GET/POST cuando se marcan o no, por lo que al final estás concatenando al SQL un valor vacío que genera un error SQL (o una cadena con `on` que hará lo mismo).

Comment: Como podría desde el formulario al resultado pasar un boolean? podría hacerlo con un select, S/N, donde los valores sean true or false

Comment: Estoy redactando la respuesta (algo a ciegas por no tener tu esquema de base de datos). En unos minutos te pongo cómo hacerlo.

Comment: gracias, los checkbox deberían de ser boolean

Comment: Ya te he redactado una respuesta, acabo de hacer una edición importante (puse un nombre de variable erróneo), prueba y me dices qué tal te ha ido.

Comment: Siento estar sometiéndote a la técnica de "prueba y error". Si compartieras el esquema en SQL en vez de captura de pantalla podría crearme la tabla en mi base de datos de pruebas. Puedes hacerlo con [`SHOW CREATE TABLE alojamientos`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html). Si lo haces desde phpmyadmin es posible que debas indicarle en el resultado que te muestre el campo completo pulsando en *+ Opciones* y luego en *Textos completos* y luego pulsando en el botón *Continuar*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que estás sufriendo es debido a que los formularios envían los elementos `checkbox` únicamente si están marcados, por lo que (por ejemplo) el valor de `$_POST['fumador']` no estará definido en caso de no marcarse y contendrá el valor `on` (o el valor configurado en el atributo `value`) si está marcado.

Los [campos booleanos en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/boolean-literals.html) son campos enteros cuyo valor `0` representa un valor falso y un `1` un valor verdadero

```
mysql> SELECT TRUE, true, FALSE, false;
    -> 1, 1, 0, 0
```

Podemos obtener el valor a insertar mediante el siguiente operador ternario:

```
empty($_POST['fumador']) ? 0 : 1;
```

Si el campo del formulario está vacío (porque no se marcó) se enviará un `0` (`false`) y en caso de haber sido marcado se enviará un `1` (`true`).

He probado con el siguiente entorno de pruebas para comprobar el funcionamiento:

```
<form action="darAltaAlojamiento.php" method="post">
  <input name="localizacion" type="text" placeholder="localizacion" /><br /><br />
  <input name="numeroHabitaciones" type="number" placeholder="numero de habitaciones" /><br /><br />
  <input name="incluidaMediaPension" type="checkbox" />Incluir media pensión<br /><br />
  <input name="fumador" type="checkbox" />fumador<br /><br />
  <input name="ninios" type="checkbox" />niños<br /><br />
  <input name="mascotas" type="checkbox" />mascotas<br /><br />
  <input name="fechaEntrada" type="date" /> Fecha Entrada<br /><br />
  <input name="fechaSalida" type="date" /> Fecha Salida<br /><br />

  <!-- Borrar los valores -->
  <label for="Borrar">¿Quieres resetear?</label>
  <input type="reset" value="Borrar" />

  <!-- Recoger los datos -->
  <label for="Enviar">Enviar</label>
  <input type="submit" name="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Y el código PHP:

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';
if (
    !empty($_POST["localizacion"])
    && !empty($_POST["numeroHabitaciones"])
    && !empty($_POST["fechaEntrada"])
    && !empty($_POST["fechaSalida"])
) {
    // Miramos si hay fila
    $consulta = $conn->prepare(
        'SELECT localizacion FROM alojamientos where localizacion = ?'
    );
    $consulta->bind_param('s', $_POST["localizacion"]);
    $consulta->execute();
    $consulta->store_result();
    if ($consulta->num_rows == 0) {
        echo "<p>No Existen registros</p>", PHP_EOL;
    }
    // Insertar datos
    $insertar = $conn->prepare('
        INSERT INTO alojamientos (
            localizacion,
            numeroHabitaciones,
            incluidaMediaPension,
            fumador,
            ninios,
            mascotas,
            fechaEntrada,
            fechaSalida
        ) VALUES (
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?
        )
    ');
    /* Asignamos la conversión para poder pasar por referencia una variable */
    $incluidaMediaPension = empty($_POST["incluidaMediaPension"]) ? 0 : 1;
    $fumador = empty($_POST["fumador"]) ? 0 : 1;
    $ninios = empty($_POST["ninios"]) ? 0 : 1;
    $mascotas = empty($_POST["mascotas"]) ? 0 : 1;
    $insertar->bind_param(
        'siiiiiss',
        $_POST["localizacion"],
        $_POST["numeroHabitaciones"],
        $incluidaMediaPension,
        $fumador,
        $ninios,
        $mascotas,
        $_POST["fechaEntrada"],
        $_POST["fechaSalida"]
    );
    if ($insertar->execute() === true) {
        die("inserted data");
    } else {
        die("failed: " . $consulta->error);
    }
}
```

Edición para responder comentario sobre agregar datos sin fechas:

```
<?php
    // Insertar datos
    $insertar = $conn->prepare('
        INSERT INTO alojamientos (
            localizacion,
            numeroHabitaciones,
            incluidaMediaPension,
            fumador,
            ninios,
            mascotas
        ) VALUES (
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?
        )
    ');
    /* Asignamos la conversión para poder pasar por referencia una variable */
    $incluidaMediaPension = empty($_POST["incluidaMediaPension"]) ? 0 : 1;
    $fumador = empty($_POST["fumador"]) ? 0 : 1;
    $ninios = empty($_POST["ninios"]) ? 0 : 1;
    $mascotas = empty($_POST["mascotas"]) ? 0 : 1;
    $insertar->bind_param(
        'siiiii',
        $_POST["localizacion"],
        $_POST["numeroHabitaciones"],
        $incluidaMediaPension,
        $fumador,
        $ninios,
        $mascotas
    );
```

Comment: no sé por que pero me consulta que no existe registro y me  no me dice nada  :S, pero gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el esquema y datos para poder probar el código? ¿Existe la `localizacion` en la tabla? En tu código original existiera o no se ejecutaba el segundo código, pero en mi código he hecho que se detenga la ejecución (con un `die()`) si no se cumple esa condición. Cambia ese `die(...)` por un `echo ...` para que siga la ejecución del programa.

Comment: actualizado, aprece que la tabla es la misma, sigue el mismo orden

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94513/discussion-on-answer-by-oscargarcia-por-que-no-me-inserta-datos-en-mysql-desde).